# Type annotation for tuples in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am working on the exercise from Introduction to Objective Caml by Jason Hickey, which asks whether there's a way to rewrite the following function, so that `nth` can take heterogeneous tuples

```
let nth i (x, y, z) =
   match i with 
    1 -> x 
  | 2 -> y 
  | 3 -> z 
  | _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "nth")
```

My solution looks like this

```
let nth 1 (x, _, _) = x
let nth 2 (_, y, _) = y
let nth 3 (_, _, z) = z
let nth _ (_, _, _) = raise (Invalid_argument "nth")
```

However, this solution does not suppress compiler from giving warning of non exhaustive matching. So I am wondering whether there's a nicer way of approaching this problem. Especially is there syntax to annotate types for tuples?

---

I attempted to do something like `let nth i (x, y, z) : 'a * 'b * 'c` where `'a * 'b * 'c` should be the type for the tuple, but I am aware that this annotation is for the return type. Hence, I would like to know whether I can specify the type for `(x, y, z)` so that it is a heterogenous tuple.

Comment: Note that if the exercise is not part of a GADT section, the exercice is probably trying to get you to answer "no".

Comment: My approach would be to write down the signature of the desired function and see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would be the function's signature?

```
val nth : int -> 'a * 'b * 'c -> ???
```

Depending on the goals, we can get away with this by writing multiple functions, or wrapping the result in a special container of a new type. The first approach gives us this:

```
val first : 'a * 'b * 'c -> 'a
val second : 'a * 'b * 'c -> 'b
val third : 'a * 'b * 'c -> 'c
```

The second approach involves wrapping the result in a variant:

```
type ('a, 'b, 'c) proj = First of 'a | Second of 'b | Third of 'c
val nth : int -> 'a * 'b * 'c -> ('a, 'b, 'c) proj
```

A variant (aka sum type, algebraic data type, tagged union) is generally how we can have different kinds of objects under the same type, safely.

Comment: The chapter hasn't talked about ADT at this point yet but I think this approach makes much sense!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your problem is that OCaml doesn't support multi-clause functions. You're not actually pattern matching on the function arguments, but defining four different functions with the same name, each shadowing the one before.

You'll need to use `match` instead:

```
let nth i tuple =
  match i, tuple with 
  | 1, (x, _, _) -> x
  | 2, (_, y, _) -> y 
  | 3, (_, _, z) -> z 
  | _ -> raise (Invalid_argument "nth")
```

Tuples types use `*` to separate elements. The type for `tuple` above is `'a * 'a * 'a`.

Update: To annotate the type of an argument, whether it's a tuple or not, you just need to surround the argument and type annotation in parentheses so it associates correctly:

```
let nth i (tuple: 'a * 'b * 'c) = ...
```

But note that this does not make the tuple heterogeneous. `'a`, `'b` and `'c` will just be inferred to be the same type. To ensure they can be different you have to specify that they are universally quantified. And to do that we have to use a different function syntax so we can specify the entire type annotation in one go:

```
let nth : 'a 'b 'c. int -> ('a * 'b * 'c) -> 'd = fun i tuple -> ...
```

Here, `'a 'b 'c. ...` means these type variables must be able to represent any type.

Comment: Yes, but the problem asks us to rewrite `nth` so that it takes heterogeneous tuples, i.e. tuples need to be type `'a -> 'b -> 'c`

Comment: Right, then you have to figure out a common type for the function to return.

Comment: Also, `'a -> 'b -> 'c` is a function type. `'a * 'b * 'c` would be the tuple type.

Comment: Right it should be 'a * 'b * 'c and that's the reason I am asking here (for a nicer solution).

Comment: The exercise is obviously hinting at a specific solution. But there is no way for us to know what that is without knwing what the book has taught you at this point. Furthermore, asking us to solve an exercise for you is too broad a question for Stack Overflow. You need to be more specific, which you have been here, and which I've answered. The rest is up to you. That's what makes it an exercise.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your answer is not answering my question, and I've posted my attempt to solve the exercise. The question is asking how to do type annotations for tuples in function declaration, which did not show up in your answer as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200164/discussion-between-kumom-and-glennsl).

Comment: I've given you the syntax for tuple types, as you asked, and told you what the immediate problem with your current attempt is. But I have not solved the exercise for you, and I won't do that, because that's considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. See the [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: I am not asking for an answer (please tell me which words in my question make you confused)...I am asking how to annotate types for tuples in function declaration, but not what the types for tuples are. See my edited question if my previous version confuses you.

Comment: I checked the two links you provide. Could you point out specifically what your concerns are? First, this is not my homework problem. Even if it is, I've provided a solution that works. Second, I've posted my attempt and only asked for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the answer. My confusion stemmed from you asking for "syntax to annotate types for tuples", when what you seem to be asking isn't  about any tuple-specific syntax, bur rather how to universally quantify type variables and how to annotate the type of a function argument.

Comment: As for why I linked to the help center: the purpose of homework and exercise is largely the same. You should learn by doing, not by being told what the solution is. You're not actually asking for a "nicer" or "more elegant" because you haven't actually solved it. But even if you had, asking for a "nicer" or "more elegant" solution is primarily opinion-based. Although it might not be if you can be specific about what "nicer" and "more elegant" means. You're also asking multiple questions in one.